# How to translate plural strings with Drush?

Tags: i18n-l10n, drush

If we want to translate a plural string in Drupal we can use the [`format_plural()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_plural/7.x) function.

If you are programming drush commands you can use the [`dt()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!includes!output.inc/function/dt/7) function to translate strings, but if you want to translate plural strings in drush wich is the function to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Between the [Drush functions that process text](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21drush%21includes%21output.inc/group/outputfunctions/7), there isn't such a function, but you can implement one using the code from [format_plural()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_plural/7.x), replacing any call to `t()` with calls to `dt()`.

```
function drush_plural($count, $singular, $plural, array $args = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $args['@count'] = $count;
  if ($count == 1) {
    return dt($singular, $args, $options);
  }

  // Get the plural index through the gettext formula.
  $index = (function_exists('locale_get_plural')) ? locale_get_plural($count, isset($options['langcode']) ? $options['langcode'] : NULL) : -1;
  // If the index cannot be computed, use the plural as a fallback (which
  // allows for most flexiblity with the replaceable @count value).
  if ($index < 0) {
    return dt($plural, $args, $options);
  }
  else {
    switch ($index) {
      case "0":
        return dt($singular, $args, $options);
      case "1":
        return dt($plural, $args, $options);
      default:
        unset($args['@count']);
        $args['@count[' . $index . ']'] = $count;
        return dt(strtr($plural, array('@count' => '@count[' . $index . ']')), $args, $options);
    }
  }
}
```